# Android VideoView - Detect point of time in video

Tags: android, listener, android-videoview

I am using a VideoView to display a video. I am using setOnPreparedListener and setOnCompletionListener to do stuff before and after the video starts and ends.

I was wondering how I could go about detecting some point of time in the video. For eg, say I want to write log to a file when the video has played for 10s. How can I detect the 10s mark?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Use `postDelayed()` or something to get control every second or so.

Step #2: Check `getCurrentPosition()` and see if it is near your desired marker point. If so, do your processing.

Step #3: Lather, rinse, repeat.

There is no mechanism for Android to call into you specifically when a certain point in time has occurred in the video, so you have to make do with a polling mechanism.

Comment: from my experience this works to a certain point, but it is not very accurate.  Maybe +/- 500ms

Comment: Is there an advantage to using postDelayed versus having a timer simply check the current position. I was wondering if there is any advantage to using handlers vs using timers in Android.

Comment: @sleeping.ninja: Timers require a thread; `postDelayed()` does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I'm an Android noob so correct me if I'm wrong. The threading happens behind the scenes right? So wouldn't it be more efficient if you set a timer to check every few millisecond on the video position(the checking happens on a separate thread). On reaching the desired position I can force something to THEN happen on the UI thread. Does that make sense? Would you call it a better approach? Don't think the performance difference would be worth even debating but I just wanted to know if using a timer was a good idea

Comment: @sleeping.ninja: "The threading happens behind the scenes right?" -- on an existing thread, called the main application thread. "So wouldn't it be more efficient if you set a timer" -- I fail to see how two threads, doing the same thing as can be done with one thread, is more efficient.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I'm quoting from Android Docs, "Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially". In my opinion it would be more efficient to have a thread that is polling for position while the main thread continues to play video content. The main thread only needs to be blocked when something is actually supposed to happen.

Comment: @sleeping.ninja: The "main thread" is not "playing video content". Video content is always played by a thread supplied by the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Is there a better solution now or is this still the 'best' way?

Comment: @Benoit: As far as I know, it is the best approach.