# How can I insert cues into a video I want to play in my Android App?

Tags: android, video, callback, cue-points

I noticed that Flash allows you to insert cue's into a video file (flv).  Is something like this possible on Android?  I have a video that runs locally in my Android app and I would like to insert cues into the video which will give me callbacks when a certain portion of the video has been reached.  If this is not possible, are there any other methods to do something similar?  I have to be pretty precise with where the cue is located.

Thanks

**Note:**
I just found this same question on stackoverflow.  Can anyone verify that this is still the case? (That it is not possible, only by polling the video continually).  I did know of this way, but it's not the most accurate way if you need to be precise and stich dynamic pieces of video together seamlessly.

[Android VideoView - Detect point of time in video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800319/android-videoview-detect-point-of-time-in-video)

Comment: Have you tried running your video in a `FrameLayout` and addind the cue in a `TextView` at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Woops I think perhaps I miscommunicated the point.  I want to put the cues into the video before the app is launched (not during).  I only want the cues to help me trigger events depending on where in the video we are.  For example, when one of the scenes in the video ends, I want to show a popup with information.

Answer (score 0):

I´m working on this as well and a kind of cue/action scripts. For tutorials, instruction video I need to keep track of current position to serve for example questions and navigation menus appropriate for that point in time. Easy when it´s sufficient to act in response to user input but otherwise firing up a thread to poll at some decent interval is the thing. Accuracy might be acceptable and can be calibrated by sensing actual position.